# Smooth transition for fade effect on tab content

Tags: javascript

I've added a fade effect to the [following tabs here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/restaurants/chinese-restaurants/mizu-brentwood-402.html), but the transition isn't smooth, especially on the last 2 tabs.

I'd like it be like [this page here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/advertise.html).

Here's the Javascipt if someone could help:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $('.tab:not(.aboutus)').fadeOut();

    $('.tabs li').click(function(){
        var thisAd = $(this).parent().parent();
        $(thisAd).children('.tab').fadeOut();
        $(thisAd).children('.'+$(this).attr('class').replace('tab','')).fadeIn();
        $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');                                                    
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

                newContent.hide();
                currentContent.fadeOut(10, function() {
                    newContent.fadeIn(100);
                    currentContent.removeClass('current-content');
                    newContent.addClass('current-content');
                });

    if(window.location.hash) {
        if (window.location.hash == "#map") {
            $(".Advert").children('.tab').fadeOut();
            $(".Advert").children('.map').fadeIn();
            $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');                                                    
            $('.maptab').addClass('active');
        }
        if (window.location.hash == "#voucher") {
            $(".Advert").children('.tab').fadeOut();
            $(".Advert").children('.vouchers').fadeIn();
        }
    }   

});
```

Many thanks.

Comment: try setting `fadeout` and `fadein` timing values and select the appropriate ..

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty smooth in my browser. Both pages are using JQuery and have essentially the same code. The only difference is that the second uses a time of 200ms for both the fadeout and fadein so try that and see if it's more to your liking.

EDIT: Sorry realised the problem. While the current view is fading out, it is still on the page and so the new view is rendered below it before jumping into the correct position after the first one has finished fading. You need to position the views absolutely so they do not affect each others position.

EDIT2: The easiest implementation is to wrap a div around the tabs and then use that:

```
<div class="tabContainer">
  <div class="tab aboutus" style="display:none">...</div>
  <div class="tab map" style="display:none">...</div>
  <div class="tab features" style="display:none">...</div>
  <div class="tab vouchers" style="display:none">...</div>
</div>
```

In css we give the container a position of relative to act as a bounding box for the tabs:

```
.tabContainer {
  position: relative;
}
```

and we give the tabs an absolute position. The top and left coordinates are relative to the container so that's why they're 0.

```
.tab {
  margin: 0 0 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

And the js:

```
$(function() { // as you're using jquery anyway you might as well use the JQuery ready function which probably suits your purposes better anyway.
      $('.tabs li').click(function(){      
          $('.tab').filter(':visible').fadeOut(200); // I'm using simpler selectors than you which will give a (very) slight performance boost (but check to make sure this won't cause any conflicts elsewhere)
          $('.tab').filter('.'+$(this).attr('class').replace('tab', '')).fadeIn(200);
          $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');                                                    
          $(this).addClass('active');
      }

      // I've deleted some code here as it doesn't do anything other than throw exceptions.

      if(window.location.hash) { // Due to the changes to the html this needs changing too.
            if (window.location.hash == "#map") {
                $('.tab').hide();
                $('.map').show();
                $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');                                                    
                $('.maptab').addClass('active');
            }
            if (window.location.hash == "#voucher") {
                $('.tab').hide();
                $('.vouchers').show();
                $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');                                                    
                $('.vouchertab').addClass('active');
            }
            else {
                $('.aboutus').show(); // even better would be to make this visible by default in css but I'll leave it as js as that's what you had in your question
            }
        }   
    });
```

Note: I've not been able to test the javascript but it should work. Let me know in the comments if you have any trouble

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you're the first one to spot there's something wrong and yes that's it, but I'm not sure how to add the absolute to the views? If you could provide an example that would be great.

Comment: Do you know why it's a smoother effect from right > left as opposed to left > right? I don't think the absolute positioning will help in this case as it's not needed.

Comment: Because when going right to left the fading in tab is already in the correct position and it's the fading out tab which gets moved (possibly off the screen in which case it will look as though it instantly disappeared and you just get the smooth animation of the new tab).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the other page is using callbacks for their animations.  After an animation completes, it executes the callback.  You can use this to smoothly `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` elements.

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
  $('.content-to-fade-out').fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $('.content-to-fade-in').fadeIn('fast')
  })
})
```

Comment: Good point. Using callbacks makes the animations happen sequentially rather than simultaneously. Your suggestion will solve the problem. I guess it's personal preference whether it looks nicer to have one fade into the next or have the animations in turn. Given that the OP asked to have an effect like the other site I suggest you probably deserve to get the accepted answer.

Comment: Haha yep.  This is one of those situations where the easiest answer is probably the best.  I think OP is a bit over his/ her head to handle a more complex solution.  Plus I think all OP wanted was the fade.  :P

Comment: Correct on both accounts...many thanks for the suggestions, I'll give this a whirl.